# Top navigation bar get corrupted and application crashed on continues tapping on menu items- iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, uinavigationbar, hamburger-menu, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have a slide out menu in my application and when I quickly tap on menu items, the navigation bar get corrupted. That is the back button in one of the screen is getting overlapped with Hamburger menu button. When tapping the overlapped combination application get crashed. I tried with making animation 'false' in the `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: false)`, but the issue still exist.

Note: The crash comes when running in device not in simulator. Everything is fine in the simulator.

I just added a screen shot of the problem below.

Comment: Can you upload your project(or reproduce the problem on a test project) so we can troubleshoot the issue? It's difficult to advise you without having  a look at the code

Comment: @BlackM I added the screen shot of the problem.